Humming Spa Motor
Have a strong spa hottub. When jets button is pushed to turned on, motor begins to Humm but no water is rotating. I manually spun the shaft in the back of the motor/pump and it spins with a slight resistance(not sure how freely it should spin). Is this the capacitor or the motor itself that needs replace.

It sounds like a capacitor problem, but they should be tested with a meter before replacing.  Slight resistance is harder, is it the weight of the motor resisting fingers to turn, or something interfering with turning.  I imagine you cannot turn the motor/shaft when in use, like a fan where you could spin the the blades to see if the capacitor is at fault.

It can also be the centrifugal switch, inside the motor, is stuck or burned -- that switch cuts out the capacitor after the motor starts.

This article may help you: https://phytomerspaetoile.com/is-your-spa-motor-humming-loudly-heres-what-you-need-to-know/
